# Sharepoint workflow wont start automatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

So I have a contact form on this website that populates a list, I then have a workflow that whenever a new item is created it sends an email with the contents of the form.

So I can actually go into the list and add a new item manually and it will send perfectly, however whenever I go and use the form on the website it does not send the email.

I've checked to make sure that the form is populating the list and it is. Anyone have any ideas why its not starting automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If your form saves the item as a system account the workflow wont start. Is the form saving as the logged in user, using impersonation or elevated privileges?